# Questioning convergences in respect to $0$: almost surely, in probability, in distribution of random variable with $\varphi$ density given.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Questioning convergences in respect to $0$: almost surely, in probability, in distribution of random variables with $\varphi_{n}(x)$, density given.

$$\varphi_n(x)=\frac{n}{\pi(1+n^2x^2)}, x\in \mathbb{R}$$
This is what I did:
$$P\{|X_n|\geq \varepsilon|\varepsilon >0\}=\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{n}{\pi(1+n^2x^2)}dx$$

If anyone could help out with this integral, I've done it myself over $\arctan..$ but I wanted to see what someone with more experience will get. After this, using the fact if:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\{X_n> \varepsilon\}< + \infty$$
then $\implies$ that the variable almost surely converges to zero.Then from there the other convergences are implied. I got that this sequence is rising and bounded, meaning, conver-ging?

Comment: Aren't you missing a $2$ factor in the integral? You need to integrate for both sides (positive and negative $x$)

Comment: But the series will *not* converge...